# How to prevent ScrollView to auto scroll to bottom?

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with my ScrollView:

If you open the Modal in my example below, the ScrollView will auto scroll to bottom.
https://snack.expo.dev/@richy88/ranting-green-chocolates?platform=web

This only happens if there is a Pressable at the bottom of the ScrollView.

I think this just happens in Web.
Is there anything wrong in my code or is this a bug in React Native?